Getting error on synthesizing the cdk project
I have the below version for my aws-cdk
D:\AWS_PYTHON_CDK>npm --version
10.5.2

D:\AWS_PYTHON_CDK>node --version
v20.12.2

D:\AWS_PYTHON_CDK>python --version
Python 3.12.3

D:\AWS_PYTHON_CDK>aws --version
aws-cli/2.15.40 Python/3.11.8 Windows/10 exe/AMD64 prompt/off

D:\AWS_PYTHON_CDK>cdk --version
2.138.0 (build 6b41c8b)

I am able to create a python cdk project inside the AWS_PYTHON_CDK folder using cdk init and the requirement.txt file is showing the dependencies to be installed as
 aws-cdk-lib==2.138.0
 constructs>=10.0.0,<11.0.0

but when I am trying to do cdk synth its throwing error, the error trace is as below.
D:\AWS_PYTHON_CDK>cdk synth
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\AWS_PYTHON_CDK\app.py", line 4, in <module>
    import aws_cdk as cdk
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aws_cdk\__init__.py", line 1511, in <module>
    from ._jsii import *
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aws_cdk\_jsii\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    __jsii_assembly__ = jsii.JSIIAssembly.load(
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jsii\_runtime.py", line 55, in load
    _kernel.load(assembly.name, assembly.version, os.fspath(assembly_path))
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jsii\_kernel\__init__.py", line 299, in load
    self.provider.load(LoadRequest(name=name, version=version, tarball=tarball))
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jsii\_kernel\providers\process.py", line 354, in load
    return self._process.send(request, LoadResponse)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jsii\_kernel\providers\process.py", line 332, in send
    self._next_message(), _ProcessResponse
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jsii\_kernel\providers\process.py", line 251, in _next_message
    return json.loads(self._process.stdout.readline(), object_hook=ohook)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 359, in loads
    return cls(**kw).decode(s)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Exception ignored in atexit callback: <bound method _NodeProcess.stop of <jsii._kernel.providers.process._NodeProcess object at 0x000002830E43D880>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jsii\_kernel\providers\process.py", line 295, in stop
    self._process.stdin.close()
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Advance Thanks for the help.

What's the output of pip freeze?

(.venv) C:\cdk_workshop>pip freeze
attrs==23.2.0
aws-cdk-lib==2.139.0
aws-cdk.asset-awscli-v1==2.2.202
aws-cdk.asset-kubectl-v20==2.1.2
aws-cdk.asset-node-proxy-agent-v6==2.0.3
cattrs==23.2.3
constructs==10.3.0
exceptiongroup==1.2.1
importlib_resources==6.4.0
jsii==1.97.0
publication==0.0.3
python-dateutil==2.9.0.post0
six==1.16.0
typeguard==2.13.3
typing_extensions==4.11.0
zipp==3.18.1

Hm, where did aws-cdk-lib 2.139.0 come from if you have 2.138.0 in your requirements.txt?
